# Python linear search with more than one element the same

Tags: python

I just started python and tried to create a simple linear search program

```py
list1=[4,2,7,5,12,54,21,64,12,32]
x=int(input("Please enter a number to search for :  "))
for i in list1:
    if x==i:
        print("We have found",x,"and it is located at index number",list1.index(i))
```

My problem is if I change the list to `[4,2,7,5,12,54,21,64,12,2,32]` it doesn't output both locations of the `2` value.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176918/finding-the-index-of-an-item-in-a-list)

Comment: Did you try to debug your program? e.g. check what's `x` and `i` in each step of the loop. That would take you into the right direction.

Answer (score 4):

This is because your are using `list1.index(i)`

`list.index()` only returns the first occurrence of the matching element only. So even when your loop is finding the second occurence of any number, this function will return the first occurence's index only.

Since you are printing the index of the searched element, you can use `enumerate` for that:

```
>>> list1 = [4,2,7,5,12,54,21,64,12,2,32]
>>> x=int(input("Please enter a number to search for :  "))
Please enter a number to search for :  2
>>> 
>>> for idx, i in enumerate(list1):
...     if x==i:
...         print("We have found",x,"and it is located at index number",idx)
... 
We have found 2 and it is located at index number 1
We have found 2 and it is located at index number 9
```

`enumerate` iterates over your `list1`, and returns a `tuple` value: `idx, i` in each iteration, where `i` is the number from your `list1`, and `idx` is its index.

Comment: @firestarter  Did this solve your problem, or do you need more help?